# How to override a vendor library with requirejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module, requirejs, marionette

I use the Marionette.js framework and I need to override a function of the Marionette.TemplateCache module but without update the marionette.js file.
So, I've created a new module for this :

```
    define(['marionette'], function (Marionette) {
    'use strict';

    _.extend(Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype, {
        loadTemplate: function(templateId){

            var template = templateId;

            if (!template || template.length === 0){
                throwError("Could not find template: '" + templateId + "'", "NoTemplateError");
            }

            return template;
        }
    });
    return Marionette;
});
```

But, I don't know how to configure my requirejs main, for when I load the Marionette.js framework , my module override Marionette.js.

Have you got any ideas how to do this?

Thanks.

Jonathan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the path defined for original library to something like `marionette-core` and update your module as follows

```
define(['marionette-core'], function (Marionette) {
'use strict';

   _.extend(Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype, {
    loadTemplate: function(templateId){

        var template = templateId;

        if (!template || template.length === 0){
            throwError("Could not find template: '" + templateId + "'", "NoTemplateError");
        }

        return template;
    }
  });

  return Marionette;
});
```

now define a path to your module as `marionette`.

So now when you require `marionette`, require.js will load original `marionette` and return your customized instance.

Plus you can still load original library using `marionette-core` somewhere else if necessary

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Your Solution works fine but i'm not satisfied by it because it's not a modular solution.
In case where we need to define another plugin in another file, we're mandatory to have a dependance between this to plugin and I don't want this.